# AllowOverride Not Working - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm attempting to figure out why it is that my .htaccess file isn't working - I'm assuming that I am somehow configuring my 000-default.conf incorrectly.

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ****.********.me
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|img|js|libs|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

/html is a symlink to /www in my CodeIgniter project.  I have removed 'index.php' from $config['index_page'], and the front page of the site loads without any issue.  It is when I attempt to access any other page on the site that the issue arises (they will not load unless I add index.php to the beginning of each).  I also ran sudo a2enmod rewrite, to no avail.  I have also restarted the apache2 service during all of my attempts at fixing the issue.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanna remove index.php, then here is the steps to follow :

1- set `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
 $config['index_page'] = '';`

2- .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Comment: Scratch that, it did work!  My issue was that I had setup my symlink incorrectly and the .htaccess wasn't being picked up in the /html folder.  Just had to add the file there and it works perfectly!  I'll mark you as correct as soon as I can.